# How to Select Today (24) Hours data

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have one column (Total_Amount) in  my table. I need to just sum today's record (last 24 hour) and I need to also sum last month in `sql server` `vb.net`.

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "Select Sum(Total_Amount) as Total_AmountSum from Table_5"
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        adapter.Fill(table)
        If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
            Label11.Text = table.Rows(0)("Total_AmountSum").ToString()
        End If
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! What specific issue are you having, it's not clear in the post?

Comment: i want sum column Total_Amount just show data of the last 24 hour

Comment: Is there an time column on this table you can look at?

Comment: i need just Total_Amount column data

Comment: first you run the code right now

Comment: So something like `... WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, date, GETDATE()) <= 24`?

Comment: u post the complete code

Comment: Just append it to your SQL query and see if it works (replace `date` with the correct date column in your table).

Comment: correct my code then post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **[DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)** here

Try this

**For last 24 hours**

```
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "Select Sum(CASE WHEN [Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN Total_Amount END) As Total_AmountSum from Table_10"
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = table.Rows(0)("Total_AmountSum").ToString()
    End If
```

**For last 1 month**

```
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "Select Sum(CASE WHEN [Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN Total_Amount END) As Total_AmountSum from Table_10"
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = table.Rows(0)("Total_AmountSum").ToString()
    End If
```

**For last 1 weak**

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "Select Sum(CASE WHEN [Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(ww, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN Total_Amount END) As Total_AmountSum from Table_10"
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim table As New DataTable()
adapter.Fill(table)
If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
    TextBox1.Text = table.Rows(0)("Total_AmountSum").ToString()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a beginning course in SQL.  Go search the internet.  W3Schools is a good place to start.

In the meantime...

```
select Sum(Total_Amount) as Total_AmountSum
from Table_5
where MyDate between dateadd(hour, -24, getdate()) and getdate()
```

...or...

```
select Sum(Total_Amount) as Total_AmountSum
from Table_5
where MyDate > dateadd(hour, -24, getdate())
```